# Simplify the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {2^i \over x^{2^i} + 1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, summation

*This question is posted for feedback which may not be appropriate for this forum.
Please let me know if this is the case. I will make sure to migrate it and/or remove it.*

I have only an elementary knowledge of sequences and series so this is how I proceeded:

We first expand the sum and write down some of the initial terms
$$
S = \sum_{i=0}^{n} {2^i \over x^{2^i} + 1} = \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{2}{x^2+1} + \frac{4}{x^4+1} 
 + \ldots + \frac{2^n}{x^{2^n}+1}
$$

Since every expression of the form $(x^k+1)$ is a factor of $(x^{2k} - 1)$ and $(x^k + 1)(x^k - 1) = (x^{2k} - 1)$;

We add and subtract the term $1 \over x-1$, and proceed by combining the terms with denominators of the above stated form

$$\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{x-1} + - \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{2}{x^2+1} + \frac{4}{x^4+1}  + \ldots + \frac{2^n}{x^{2^n}+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{-2}{x^2-1} + \frac{2}{x^2+1} + \frac{4}{x^4+1}  + \ldots + \frac{2^n}{x^{2^n}+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{-4}{x^4-1} + \frac{4}{x^4+1}  + \ldots + \frac{2^n}{x^{2^n}+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{-8}{x^8-1} + \frac{8}{x^8+1} + \ldots + \frac{2^n}{x^{2^n}+1} \\
\end{align}$$

Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{-2^n}{x^{2^n}-1} + \frac{2^n}{x^{2^n}+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{-2^{n+1}}{x^{2^{n+1}}-1} \\
\end{align}$$

Hence, the result

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} {2^i \over x^{2^i} + 1} = \frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{2^{n+1}}{x^{2^{n+1}}-1} \\$$

- Is this result (and its derivation) correct?
- Can any further simplification be performed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{2}{x^2+1} + \frac{4}{x^4+1} + \cdots $ up to $n$ terms in terms of $x$ and $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528731/frac1x1-frac2x21-frac4x41-cdots-up-to-n-terms-in) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cfrac%7B2%5Ei%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%5Ei%7D%2B1%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: The duplicate shows your result & derivation is correct, & I'm unaware of any further specific simplifications. FYI, other duplicates include [Prove the identity $\frac{1}{1+x^{1}}+\cdots+\frac{2^{n}}{1+x^{2^{n}}}=\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{2^{n+1}}{1+x^{2^{n+1}}}$](/q/3897133) and [Find the sum : $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{2^i}{1+x^{2^{i}}}$](/q/789008). Also, this [answer](/a/777982) gives the general solution to a question asking for only $n=4$, and a closely related question is [Show that $\frac {1} {r-1} = \frac {1} {r+1} + \frac {2} {r^2+1} + \frac {4} {r^4+1} +\cdots$](/q/2123430).

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks for pointing out the error, I have fixed it now.
And thank you for providing the links to the duplicate questions the last one is particularly helpful :).